# Show that trace class is a banach space with respect to norm $\|\|_{S_1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, trace

Show that trace class is a banach space with respect to norm $\| \|_{S_1}$ where the norm is infinite sum of eigenvalues of $(T^*T)^\frac{1}{2}$ and T is a compact operator in a separable hilbert space.  I think this should follow quite easily when using the fact that space is complete if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\|x_k\| < \infty$ implies that the series convergence in norm.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Depending on what you know about the trace class and the trace, it might be easier to show that the trace class can be identified with the dual of the space of compact operators endowed with the operator norm (the dual of a normed space is complete).

Comment: As the other commenter notes, the easiest way to prove this will depend on what exactly you know and have already developed about the trace class and the trace.  How, for example, have you shown that $\|\cdot\|_{S_1}$ is a norm (or that the trace class, which is a proper subset of the set of compact operators whenever the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional, is even closed under addition)?